# Netlogo file open error "expected nlogo file to have 12 sections, this has 1"

Tags: file, netlogo, sections

I'm getting the error

> expected nlogo file to have 12 sections, this has 1.

I understand that a file has 12 sections, but I don't know what that means or why my model all of the sudden has one. I know that the sections are as follows:

```
Code tab
@#$#@#$#@
Interface tab   
@#$#@#$#@
Info tab
@#$#@#$#@
turtle shapes
@#$#@#$#@
NetLogo version
@#$#@#$#@
preview commands
@#$#@#$#@
System Dynamics Modeler
@#$#@#$#@
BehaviorSpace
@#$#@#$#@
HubNet client
@#$#@#$#@
link shapes
@#$#@#$#@
model settings
@#$#@#$#@
DeltaTick
@#$#@#$#@
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: I am wondering if you tried to open a file from a very old version of NetLogo. You could use a text editor to compare your problem model to a new model from the Models Library and see if there's an obvious structure difference.

Comment: JenB is correct.  The NetLogo Web FAQ has [a section about this](https://netlogoweb.org/info#model-format-error).  It's worth noting that the section delimiters do need to be on their own lines, if you're trying to make your own model files.

Comment: You have one too many section dividers in your example code.